# Типы данных mysql

Tags: mysql

Доброго времени суток. Созрел вопрос, с которым я уже давно пытался разобраться, но нигде не получалось найти исчерпывающую информацию. А вопрос состоит из нескольких более мелких и заключается в использовании разных типов данных в mysql. Конкретнее, хотелось бы получить информацию по всем типам данных и понять, в каком случае какой тип лучше использовать. К примеру, для переключателей (0 - 1) я обычно использую tinyint(1). А не лучше ли enum('0','1')? Или для даты я использую int(11), а не лучше ли bigint(20)? И т.п. Итак:

1. Чем отличается tinyint от smallint, int, bigint и подобных int? И что означает число в скобочках после типа?
2. Тот же вопрос про text. И с какого количества символов varchar становится text?
3. И то же самое про blob. Целесообразно ли этот формат использовать для хранения текта?
4. Для чего на практике нужны datetime и timestamp?

Ну, и парочку примеров, для чего вы используете тот или иной тип данных.
Заранее спасибо.

П.С.: id - это int. А если известно, что id вряд ли превысит тысячу, то чем его лучше объявить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Прочитай про типы данных в официальной доке, там есть [ответы на почти все твои вопросы](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/data-types.html).
- datetime и timestamp на практике нужны (сюрприз-сюрприз!) для хранения даты и таймстампа :) Не стоит хранить дату в int-е, зачем закрывать себе доступ к функциям работы с датами? Это наверное из-за боязни тайм зон? Тогда советую прочесть ещё и это [daylight-saving-time-and-timezone-best-practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532729/daylight-saving-time-and-timezone-best-practices)
- id я всегда объявляю long-ом (bigint) и всем советую. Экономить байты имеет смысл в больших таблицах. В больших таблицах id всегда большой, а в маленьких разницы никакой.
- Для флажков лучше использовать BOOL. Это синоним для tinyint(1). Енумы надо использовать когда у тебя возможных значений больше двух.
- BLOB и Text отличаются от варчара тем что они хранятся не в таблице а "сбоку". => Селектить их дольше. 
  `"Each BLOB or TEXT value is represented internally by a separately allocated object. This is in contrast to all other data types, for which storage is allocated once per column when the table is opened"`

Comment: Почитаю, спасибо). Но чем отличается int(11) от int(10) и int(1) tinyint(1) все равно не понял.  
Если мне не нужно работать со временем (только сохранить/загрузить из БД), то лучше использовать int, так?  
Если есть проект с небольшим количеством пользователей, но с большим количеством связанных данных, стоит ли объявлять id bigint'ом или можно сэкономить еще спичек?

Comment: Про int(x). В доке же всё написано. Это не на что не влияет. "MySQL supports an extension for optionally specifying the display width of integer data types in parentheses following the base keyword for the type. For example, INT(4) specifies an INT with a display width of four digits. " ... " Nor does it prevent values wider than the column display width from being displayed correctly. For example, a column specified as SMALLINT(3) has the usual SMALLINT range of -32768 to 32767, and values outside the range permitted by three digits are displayed in full using more than three digits."

Comment: про время - нет не так. Если поле представляет время, используй тип данных "время". Это сделает структуру базы самодокументированной, позволит базе выполнять автоматическую проверку корректности этого времени, ну и сегодня ты с датами не работаешь, а завтра начнёшь..;) Внутри mysql-я дата всё равно хранится как инт, ничего ты не соптимизируешь.

Comment: Если данных мало - не парься с оптимизацией. Что тебе даст использование коротких идшников в маленькой базе, например использоваться вместо long-a int? По идее у тебя индексы и таблицы станут чуть меньше, допустим даже на 10%. Значит теоретически один блок данных у тебя будет вмещать на 10% строк больше, и твоя табличка будет не 10 мегабайт а 9. И что? Всё равно она будет считана с диска одной операций последовательного чтения и попадёт в кэш и будет жить там практически вечно. Заоптимизировал что-нибудь? На больших базах (от 10 гиг) уже можно подумать...